# Moving Vue components around inside the dom?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am moving Vue components up in the dom if I am on mobile since I want to use positioning absolute and want to make sure I am not within a `relative` container.

```
if (this.mobile) {
    this.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$el);
    document.getElementById('vue').appendChild(this.$el);
} else {
    // Place the element back at it's original location.
}
```

This code is placed with a debounced `resize` method so it also works on resizing of the window.

It works fine but when I start out on mobile and resize back to desktop I need to get the original dom location of where the component was first initialized.

This might be a Javascript only question but how can I get the original location of the exact dom position of this component so I can place it back again?

**Edit**

I am saving the initial parent element with:

```
this.parent = this.$el.parentElement;
```

This does not guarantee the right order in the parent element though when I append the element back to the parentElement again.

Comment: I'd put a hidden marker element in the original location that can be replaced when you move the element back.  (But before that I'd see if I could refactor the design to not require rearranging the DOM in the first place...)

Comment: @DanielBeck sounds like a good idea. The design can not be changed I need a fullscreen overlay and position fixed is too buggy for this. I therefore need to use position absolute but I also need to ensure it is not inside a relative container. I'm afraid there is no other option.

Comment: Fair enough!  Another approach would be to just have duplicate components each with a `v-if` based on window size; that might be better than rearranging the DOM manually

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this.  You should be using media queries to style based on specific viewport sizes.

Comment: @DavidL if a component is deeply nested in HTML you can not use media queries to fix this and make the component fullscreen. The only way you could achieve that is by removing the `relative` position on all container elements for that component which is insane.

Comment: @Stephan-v without seeing any example code I'll have to take your word for it :).  But typically this is a CSS problem, not a JS problem.

Comment: This should be a CSS problem which can be dealt with in 2 minutes flat if `position fixed` was not bugged in Safari Mobile and other mobile browsers. This turns this into a JS problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just want to save the original `parentNode` once and use it when you need it. Something like this ought to work. Depending on your setup, you might need to use [`insertBefore`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp) with Daniel Beck's hidden marker idea.

```
if (!this.originalParentNode) {
    this.originalParentNode = this.$el.parentNode;
}
if (this.mobile) {
    this.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$el);
    document.getElementById('vue').appendChild(this.$el);
} else {
    // Place the element back at its original location.
    this.originalParentNode.appendChild(this.$el);
}
```