# How to attach a Vue Bootstrap Modal to a different parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

Currently using a [Vue Bootstrap Modal](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/) which doesn't display properly, because it's parent (or rather an ancestor up the tree) has a `overflow:hidden` defined.

Is there a way to have the modal attach to, say, the `body`-element instead?

Of course, I could reorganize my templates, but this modal logically belongs to the component it's current defined in, and I don't want to break that.

Comment: wouldn't a static container below body suffice? i.e. `id="themodal"` (maybe with a 'modal' router-view for the content) - because - there can only ever be 1 modal displayed at a given time

Comment: nvm. bs-vue doc: `Unlike native Bootstrap V4, BootstrapVue supports multiple modals opened at the same time.`

Comment: well, but then I'd have to separate out my logic, i.e.: modals not nicely contained in component where it belongs to anymore, which is something I was hoping to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I just noticed you're not using vanilla Bootstrap but its Vue.js incarnation. I'll still leave this up since it might help.

I don't see any built-in way to do it in Vue. Have you considered something like this in your component:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

// ...

mounted() {
  $(this.$refs.myModal).appendTo('body');
  // I guess you can still drive this.$refs.myModal even though it's not a child of this.$el
  // after this point?
  // Also cache this.$refs.myModal somewhere for below
},

updated() {
  // Check if this.$refs.myModal is the same element as the cached element
  // If not, it has been recreated so remove the cached node from "body" and:
  $(this.$refs.myModal).appendTo('body');
},

beforeDestroy() {
  $(this.$refs.myModal).appendTo(this.$el);
},
```

jQuery is not required of course, but you're already using it with Bootstrap so why not use it here too.

## Update

I found this Github issue discussing this same problem: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1108

Apparently, relocating DOM elements outside Vue components can cause issues sometimes. See the issue for more details.

There's also [PortalVue](https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue) that allows relocating components.

See also:

- [Moving Vue components around inside the dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166973/moving-vue-components-around-inside-the-dom)
- https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-it-bad-practice-to-manually-move-a-components-element-to-a-different-position-in-the-dom/9026/6

Comment: "you're already using it with Bootstrap" AFAIK:  vue-bootstrap ships with its own vue-based js and jq is not neccessary/required

Comment: Yes, hence the disclaimer :)

Comment: Yeah, it's the best alternative I could come up with. Still feels rather hacky though. Keeping this open for a while to see if something better comes along. Otherwise I'll accept. Thanks